# Import data From Excel to special list of tuples - Python

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel (.xlsx) file that has 3 columns. For example :

```
machine  time   continuity
1         3         ()
2         4         (1,)
1         3         (2,)
3         1         ()
1         2         (4,)
2         3         (3, 5)
```

I want to import it in Python and to get a list of tuples like:

```
jobs = [
        [(1, 3, ()), (2, 4, (1,)), (1, 3, (2,)), (3, 1, ()), (1, 2, (4,)), (2, 3, (3, 5))]
    ]
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work. We need to use `to_numpy` for this. You'll get a numpy array then

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
df_list = df.to_numpy().tolist()
output_data = [tuple(list) for list in df_list]
print(output_data)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you for a help. It works, but column continuity is shaped '()' and and I don't know how to get rid of quotes.

Comment: I tried this, but there are still quotes in the result:

    `df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")   
    mylist = list(map(list, df.to_numpy()))
    print (mylist)`
 
   `[[40, 1, 3, '()'], [41, 2, 4, '(1,)'], [42, 1, 3, '(2,)'], [43, 3, 1, '()'], [50, 1, 2, '(4,)'], [47, 2, 3, '(3, 5)']]`

Comment: The quotes are appearing while displaying the content but they are not in the data. If you print the value instead of string you'll have it.  ` print(output_data[0]) ` try this